# How to loop through large file and output lines to curl through stdin?

Tags: bash, stdin, gnu-parallel

Say somefile contains the content

```
a
b
c
```

I want each line to be turned into 3 http POST curl commands. So line 3 would post "c" to some url.

I can loop through the file with bash and dump to curl like this

```
cat somefile | while read line; \
  do curl -XPOST 'www.example.com' -d "$line"; \
done
```

However, line is a giant json file and sometimes passing it through the command line does weird things. I'd rather have something like this

```
cat somefile | parallel curl -XPOST example.com -d @-
```

where '@-' means each line of file is passed to curl through stdin. gnu parallel can accept {} as an argument which is similar to "$line" above, but I'd like something that turns a file in to a stream of lines before passing it to the next command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat somefile | parallel --pipe -N1 curl -XPOST example.com -d @-
```

Answer (score 1):

[ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) says:

```
Line 1:
cat somefile | while read line; \
                     ^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.
```

This would explain it doing weird things to JSON, which frequently uses backslashes:

```
$ echo '{ "key": "some value with \"nested quotes\" here" }' | \
      while read line; do echo "$line"; done
{ "key": "some value with "nested quotes" here" }
```

Adding the `-r` will instead leave them alone:

```
$ echo '{ "key": "some value with \"nested quotes\" here" }' | \
      while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done
{ "key": "some value with \"nested quotes\" here" }
```

To be entirely correct, it should be `while IFS= read -r line` to also preserve leading spaces.

---

Relevant [POSIX docs for `read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html):

> By default, unless the -r option is specified, < backslash> shall act as an escape character. An unescaped < backslash> shall preserve the literal value of the following character, with the exception of a < newline>. If a < newline> follows the < backslash>, the read utility shall interpret this as line continuation. The < backslash> and < newline> shall be removed before splitting the input into fields. All other unescaped < backslash> characters shall be removed after splitting the input into fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat somefile | parallel 'echo {} | curl -XPOST example.com -d @-'
```